# Destructuring array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I am trying to do array destructuring in javascript and encounter some very puzzling behavior

Here's the code I have --

```
 let res = {
            start: {},
            end: {},
        };
[res.start.hour, res.start.minute] = [7, 20]
[res.end.hour, res.end.minute] = [17, 30]
console.log(res)
```

The output is

```
{ start: { hour: 17, minute: 30 }, end: {} }
```

For some reason, [17, 30] were assigned to res.start, instead of res.end.

Furthermore, if I add a console.log statement like below

```
 let res = {
            start: {},
            end: {},
        };
[res.start.hour, res.start.minute] = [7, 20]
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
[res.end.hour, res.end.minute] = [17, 30]
console.log(res)
```

Then it works. res.end would get the correct value.
Output --

```
{"start":{"hour":7,"minute":20},"end":{}}
{ start: { hour: 7, minute: 20 },
  end: { hour: 17, minute: 30 } }
```

I've searched, and read thru MDN page on destructure, but couldn't find an explanation to this.
Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You need to use a semicolon after `[7, 20]`

Comment: `[res.start.hour, res.start.minute] = [7, 20]
[res.end.hour, res.end.minute] = [17, 30]` needs to be `[res.start.hour, res.start.minute] = [7, 20];
[res.end.hour, res.end.minute] = [17, 30];`

Comment: Always use semicolons unless you're *certain* of your knowledge about ASI, else you'll run into troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let res = {
  start: {},
  end: {}
};
[res.start.hour, res.start.minute] = [7, 20]; // Notice the semicolons.
[res.end.hour, res.end.minute] = [17, 30];
console.log(res);
```

I copy-pasted your code from the first block into VS Code and used 'Alt + Shift + F' (auto-formatting). It fixed the code to the following, indicating that something is clearly off:

```
let res = {
  start: {},
  end: {}
};
[res.start.hour, res.start.minute] = [7, 20][(res.end.hour, res.end.minute)] = [
  17,
  30
];
console.log(res);
```

As it turns out, semicolons do matter sometimes in JavaScript.

Comment: My goodness. Thank you so much.